# What is srand(getpid()) and rand() doing below?

Tags: c, random, ipc, fork, srand

I'm looking to create a priority list filled with PIDs from forked processes in a Unix environment. I found the following section of code but I don't understand what the rand and srand(getpid()) are accomplishing. How is a 'priority list' created through use of random numbers?

I know that `rand() % (100 - 1) +1;` gives you a random number but why has the author of the code bothered to add 1 after subtracting it?

```
for(B = 0; B < noToCreate; B++)     
    {
        pid = fork();

        if(pid == -1)
        {
            perror("Error forking");
            exit(1);
        }
        else if(pid > 0)
        {
            wait(0);
        }
        else
        {
            srand(getpid());

            while(x == 0)
            {
                if(*randNum == 101)
                {
                    *randNum = rand() % (100 - 1) + 1;
                    *pidNum = getpid();

                    printf("priority: %d Process ID: %d \n", *randNum, *pidNum);

                    x = 1;
                }
                else
                {
                    *randNum++;
                    *pidNum++;
                }
            }
            exit(0);
        }
    } /* Closes main for loop */
```

Thanks guys! :)

Comment: It is not clear what your question is. Your title claims that you are asking about `srand` and `rand`, if so you should look up the `man` pages first. The question text then looks more that you want to know something about the precedence rules of the expression `x % (100 - 1) + 1`.

Answer (score 1):

The [`srand`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/numeric/random/srand) function seeds the random number generator used by [`rand`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/numeric/random/rand). This is to ensure that you don't get the same sequence of number every time you run your program.

The normal use is to use the current time as returned by [`time`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/chrono/time), but any "seemingly" random number will do. And no, you can't use `rand` to create the seed, as without a previous seeding the first `rand` call in a program will always return the same number.

As for the `rand() % (100 - 1) +1` part, it's to get a random number between 1 and 100. It's done by *first* dividing the random number with 99 (100 - 1) and use the remainder which is between 0 and 99, *then* add 1 to get a value between 1 and 100.

Comment: 1 to 100 but not equal to 100 the range is [1,99] actually.

Comment: Thanks! I understand the seeding and how rand() % (100-1) + 1 works / what it does now! :)

I thought a priority list would have to be sorted but wouldn't the printf statement simply print out random numbers, with their corresponding PID values, in a completely unsorted fashion?

Also, why does he seed getpid() when PIDs are set by parent processes and 'shared' to child processes?

You guys have helped loads already! Thanks! :D